# Using PHP variable in system() function

Tags: php, batch-file, web, cmd

I am currently using this command:
`system('"C:/xampp/htdocs/csv/txtfiles/PSPPfile.txt"');`

I want to having something like with having variable inside, for instance:

```
$file='txtfiles/PSPPfile.txt';
system('"C:/xampp/htdocs/csv/$file"');
```

Something like above, kindly help me out. Thanks!

Comment: You need to concatenate your string as variables are not expanded inside a single-quoted string.

Comment: can you pls give me an example? @jeroen

Comment: `system('"C:/xampp/htdocs/csv/' . $file . '"');`

Comment: That is not the same command as the one in your question on the first line.

Comment: well, i mean 
`system(' "C:\xampp\htdocs\csv\" '.$file);`

Comment: That is also not the same as the one in your question.

Comment: It is same. that's what being asked. One of the answers are below.
Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Single quoted strings will display things almost completely "as is." Variables and most escape sequences will not be interpreted.

In other words, youre assigning the argument to `system` to read $file as is, not as what the variable contains.

Use double quotes to assert that variable gets replaced - or perform string concatenation :

```
 system( 'c:/xampp/htdocs/csv/' . $file );
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$file = 'txtfiles/PSPPfile.txt';
system('C:/xampp/htdocs/csv/' . $file);
```

Comment: A little description is always helpful.